# Creating a lookup function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lookup

I want to create a python lookup function for students. I have a tab delimited file with ID and students name. I want to create a lookup program such that entering either a student's name or ID will return name of the student and student ID if a match has been found.

So far I have imported the data successfully. Snippet of [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADc5K4PTP5xVy6X5gbfCD6BV_Z7WKkLQ/view?usp=sharing)  is shared. Having trouble defining a function. I am sharing my code below:

```
infile = open("D:/work/student_id.txt",  "r")

def lookup():
word =raw_input("code to lookup: ")
print ("\n")
n = elements.index(word)
x = elements[n][0]
y = elements[n][0]
if word == x:
    print x, ":", y, "\n"
else:
    print("That code does not exist")
lookup()
```

I searched online(stackoverflow-found post by Erik and Alexander, I tried to model my code like theirs but still no help; O'riley books on Python) for help regarding creation of lookup function but they all involved writing the data out. But I found no guidance on creating a lookup function for an imported tab delimited file. I hope this will help others as well. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Python are you using?
Python 3 uses `input()`, not `raw_input()`.
As your file is tab-separated you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) function.

```
import csv
students = {}
search = input()
found = None
with open('student_id.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
       students[row[0]] = row[1]
    print(students)
    for i in students.keys():
       if search == i:
           found = search + " " + students[i]
       else:
           if search == students[i]:
               found = i + " " + students[i]
    if found == None:
        print("Not found")
    else:
        print(found)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was hoping for the result to return student id and the associated name. This one returns either student id or name(which ever is entered) but not both. But the code you provided still works! Any hints on how to make it return both id and associated full name? Thank you once again!!

Comment: Forgot to answer your question, I use Python 3. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Awesome! Works for me too. Thank you very berry much!!